# systemd: How to stop a start-job without limit

Tags: systemd

Is there a way I can stop a systemd start-job that is configured without no limit?

I am not asking where I can reconfigure the limit - I want to stop while it is waiting for it.

I do not have another console to enter the system.
If I hit Ctrl+Alt+Del then the jobs went to shutdown.

I just want to stop the waiting for this unlimited job that has a problem at startup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably not possible (for security reasons) to stop a systemd start-job while booting. From this [post](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/838#issuecomment-127904396):

```
Q: how can you have control whilst booting? IIRC my keyboard ctrl+c break attempts do not work.
```

> A: Well, you cannot, for security reasons... We cannot allow altering
>   the boot process just from the screen without authentication...
>
> If you run "systemctl enable debug-shell" you can turn on a debug
>   shell on tty9 that runs continously from earliest boot on. But that of
>   course can only be done on the previous boot.

As mentioned in above thread it might be possible to use a debug shell (if it is already enabled), but this is only recommended for debugging and not for permanent use. From the [systemd documentation](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/):

> **Early Debug Shell**
>
> You can enable shell access to be available very early in the startup
>   process to fall back on and diagnose systemd related boot up issues
>   with various systemctl commands. Enable it using:
>
> `systemctl enable debug-shell.service`
>
> or by specifying
>
> `systemd.debug-shell=1`
>
> on the kernel command line.
>
> Tip: If you find yourself in a situation where you cannot use
>   systemctl to communicate with a running systemd (e.g. when setting
>   this up from a different booted system), you can avoid communication
>   with the manager by specifying --root=:
>
> `systemctl --root=/ enable debug-shell.service`
>
> Once enabled, the **next time you boot you will be able to switch to
>   tty9 using CTRL+ALT+F9** and have a root shell there available from an
>   early point in the booting process. You can use the shell for checking
>   the status of services, reading logs, looking for stuck jobs with
>   systemctl list-jobs, etc.
>
> **Warning: Use this shell only for debugging! Do not forget to disable
>   systemd-debug-shell.service after you've finished debugging your boot
>   problems. Leaving the root shell always available would be a security
>   risk.**
>
> It is also possible to alias kbrequest.target to debug-shell.service
>   to start the debug shell on demand. This has the same security
>   implications, but avoids running the shell always.